# Javascript link builder within HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button, hyperlink

I'm trying to build a... link builder to ease some of my day-to-day tasks. I can't make it work though, and would really appreciate some help:

```
<form target="">
  ID one:
  <input type="text" name="IDone" id="ID1">
  
  ID two:
  <input type="text" name="IDtwo" id="ID2">
  
  <button value="go" id="myButton">build</button>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = 
          "https://first.part.com/" + document.getElementById("ID1").value +
          "?act=setsecond_part=" + document.getElementById("ID2").value;
    };
  </script>
  
</form>
```

The idea is very simple:

- first field (ID one) gets the data that's put in it;
- second field (ID two) gets the data that's put in it;
- the "build" button actually goes to link that's comprised of https://first.part.com/ +  + <?act=setsecond_part=> + <"ID2">.

Thank you for your assistance!

JPM

Comment: It is really hard to read code like this.

Comment: didn't see that one coming, thanks a bunch for the edit!

Comment: Does the function ever get called? If yes, what is the value of location.href after the call?

Comment: Hi, no, it doesn't get called; don't know how I thought the "build" button would call it... Can you suggest how to call the function through the "build" button so it actually goes to the newly built link?

Answer (score 1):

Delete a form tag and everything will be work fine :)

Comment: Thanks!!! :)
Don't know why the <form> </form> was messing it up, but now it's working.